# How to initialize an array inside a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist, indexing

So I am creating a function to filter one by ones images (arrays) concatenated in a list, that variable is called *images*. The filtered images are saved in a new list variable with the same characteristics of the original one in shape and data type. List length: 52, Array shape:  [846, 1512, 3]

```
def bi_blur(images):
    bi_img = [np.zeros(images[0].shape,dtype='uint8')]*len(images)
    for image in range(len(images)):
        bi_img[image][:,:,0] = cv.bilateralFilter(images[image][:,:,0], 20, 50, 50)
    return bi_img
```

Now, the problem is that every time I do the filtering in one item of the list (an image), this one is assigned to all the items of the new list, so at the end I am getting a 52 item list with the same filtered array on them. I checked the index variable *image* used in the for loop and it is working properly so I don't know what else could be wrong.

[This is the result, every for iteration all the arrays/images inside the array are updated to the same values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNxdr.png)

Comment: Looks like the multiple references problem.      `bi_img = [np.zeros(images[0].shape,dtype='uint8') for i in range(len(images))]`

Comment: It easily worked just changing that line, thank you so much!

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change
`bi_img = [np.zeros(images[0].shape,dtype='uint8')]*len(images)`

to
`bi_img = [np.zeros(images[0].shape,dtype='uint8') for i in range(len(images))]`

The first one creates multiple references to the same object.
The second one creates the copies.

Read [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)  for more information on python variables naming and references.